# Simple web scrappin on google maps

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using this [github code](https://github.com/padmanabhan-s/scraping-google-map/blob/master/scraping%20google%20map%20%20with%20python%20using%20selenium(chrome)%20and%20beautifulsoup.py) to try to get the place name from maps given when give a link with the lat and lon.
so I found that the place name is this part of html code.
`<span jstcache="213" class="DkEaL" jsan="7.DkEaL">Labateca, Norte de Santander</span>`
But I'm unable to understand how to properly reffer to get just the name
Labateca, Norte de Santander

Comment: Have you already checked your `soup` if class name exists? Try to avoid selecting by class name, cause in most cases they are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In the source is already a similar example (copy and change it with your parameters):

```
phone = soup.find("span", {"class": "LrzXr zdqRlf kno-fv"})    
assert phone, "could not find element"
phone = phone.text

name = soup.find("span", {"class": "DkEaL"})
assert name, "could not find element"
name = name.text

print(f"Phone: {phone}, Name: {name}")
```

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)